# Page Formatting Drop-Down

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently started working on a project for a new webpage.  My only problem is that on some web browsers (Apple Safari, Mozilla Firefox) the text and images are shifted of way to far to the left.  I wanted to know if I could make a drop-down box that would change the percent the text is to the left.

If there is a more simple way of making the format appear normal on all browsers and monitors please let me know.

My code looks like this:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>GameLikeBacon.com</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <IMG SRC="background.gif">
        </center>
        <DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:100px; left: 15%; width:950px; height:1150px">
            <center>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    // Empty JavaScript Section, Cookies Not Working
                </script>
                <left><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/ethan1bacon56?feature=mhee">
    <img src="logo.gif" onmouseover="this.src='logos.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='logo.gif'" style="border-style: none"/>
    </a>
                </left>
                <center><a href="Action Games.html"><img src="actionbutton1.gif" 
      onmouseover="this.src='actionbutton2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='actionbutton1.gif'"    style="border-style: none"/></a>
 <a href="Adventure Games.html" style="font-family: AR JULIAN; font-size: 25px;">Adventure </a>
 <a href="Arcade Games.html" style="font-family: AR JULIAN; font-size: 25px">Arcade </a>
 <a href="Sports Games.html" style="font-family: AR JULIAN; font-size: 25px;">Sports </a>
 <a href="Strategy Games.html" style="font-family: AR JULIAN; font-size: 25px">Strategy  </a>
                </center>
                 <h2 align="left">Newest Game: Plants vs. Zombies</h2>
 <a href="Plants vs. Zombies.html">
    <img src="zombie.jpg" style="border-style: none;" align="left">
    </a>

                 <h2 align="right">Featured Game: Fancy Pants 1</h2>
 <a href="Fancy Pants 1.html">
    <img src="Fancy.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='Fancy2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='Fancy.jpg'" style="border-style: none" align="right">
    </a>

                <right>
                    <img src="Bacon.gif">
                </right>
                <center>
                    <p style="font-size: 35px;">Newest Games</p>
                </center>
                <center><a href="Plants vs. Zombies.html" style="font-size: 25px;"> Plants vs. Zombies </a>
 <a href="Johnny Upgrade.html" style="font-size: 25px;"> Johnny Upgrade </a>
                </center>
                <center>
                    <h1>----------------------------------------</h1>
                </center>
                <center><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/ethan1bacon56?feature=mhee"><img src="Ad.gif" style="border-style: none;"></a>
                </center>
                <center>
                    <h6>Want your advertisment here?  Contact me at ethandpeck@hotmail.com</h6>
                </center>
                <img src="splash.gif">
        </DIV>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to do this or can I use the drop down to decide the percent the text is to the left?  By the way, I am 11 so don't downvote me because this may seem simple.

Comment: To start with, the `center` tag should never be used, and there is no such thing as a `left` tag. I'd start by building a very simple version of the layout that you want with empty boxes, and then adding your content back in. If you're looking for a quick way to get your site consistent, check out Twitter Bootstrap's [grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

Comment: Now my page is completly messed up.